# Array required, but object found

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create an accessor for a custom object, `Room`, which has a grid of tiles each with an integer value. I want the `getSteps` method to return that integer value, given coordinates for the associated `Room` object; I also want the `steppedOn` method to increment it by one.

```
public Room(int tilesLong, int tilesWide) {
    length = tilesLong + 2;
    width = tilesWide + 2;
}

 private int getSteps(int tileX, int tileY) {
    int steps = this[tileX][tileY];  //Problem code
    return steps;
}

public void steppedOn(int tileX, int tileY) {
    System.out.println(room[tileX][tileY] + 1);
}
```

I understand this probably isn't the correct approach, but I'm lost on how else to do it.

Comment: @sumeetkumar next time instead of commenting, if you know there's an issue with the tags you can change them yourself.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts will do !! Thanks

Comment: `this` refers to the object. It doesn't make any sense to do `[tileX][tileY]` on an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

online:

```
int steps = this[tileX][tileY];  //Problem code
```

you are trying to save you are calling an `array` improperly

First, you will need to declare an `array`. and in your signature, state the value you want to pass into the array. so it will look something like this:

```
public class room {

   int length, width;
   int[][] steps;

   public room(int tilesLong, int tilesWide) {
       length = tilesLong + 2;
       width = tilesWide + 2;
       steps = new int[width][length];
   }

   private int getSteps(int tileX, int tileY, int step) {
       this.steps[tileX][tileY] = step;
       return steps[tileX][tileY];
   }

   public void steppedOn(int tileX, int tileY) {
       System.out.println(steps[tileX][tileY] + 1);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) for `this`:

> Within an instance method or a constructor, `this` is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called.

So in your `getSteps()` method you are trying to call `[tileX][tileY]` on an *object* which doesn't really make sense. If the object has a 2d `array` class variable you need to call `[tileX][tileY]` on the `array` and not directly on `this`.

> I also want the `steppedOn` method to increment it by one.

In your `steppedOn()` method you only print the number plus one. However this just increments the number that you print out, not the actual value. To actually increment the value do

```
public void steppedOn(int tileX, int tileY) {
     System.out.println(room[tileX][tileY]++);
}
```